# Google API Oauth token in firefox webextension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, google-oauth

I am trying to fetch Oauth2 token for Google Drive API in Firefox Webextension.
I use background.html to load google Javascript client library. However When  authorize using gapi.auth.authorize is invoked, nothing happens.

My analysis that  "authorize" tries to open new window for User to allow/deny permissions but fails.

Similar thing is achieved in chrome extension with chrome.identity executing in chrome's background.js

Content security policy in manifest.json

```
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://apis.google.com; object-src 'self'"
```

Is there any better way to receive Oauth2 token for Google API ? and What am I missing in above approach ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @s007: Were you able to find a solution for this. I am also working on similar firefox extension where I require google auth. However I find that the 'auth' object is not loading and giving an error gapi.auth is undefined.